# Cornered "clipped" edges but only on the bottom 2 and smooth wrap

Tags: html, css

[image]

So the picture above is what I am trying to achieve . And this is what I've gotten:

[image]

My issue is I can't quite get the upper edges to wrap around correctly, they feel too sharp. I've played around a lot with `clip-path` but i'm unsure if `clip-path` is the best method to use for this or if there's better methods.

```
  .center-nav-menu {
    width: 15rem;
    overflow:hidden;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 25%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 25%)
  }

  .button-default {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 9px 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #565565;
  }
```

The html is just a basic

```
  <div :class="itemClasses">
    <span>{{ label }}</span>
  </div>
```

Anyone have any links or suggestions? Is clip-path the correct way? I thought about also just "faking" it with a background image too. But just wanted some advice. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider a skew transformation applied on pseudo elements

```css
button {
  --r: .7em; /* the radius */
  --a: 10deg; /* the curvature */

  padding: .6em 1.5em;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
button:before,
button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset-block: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: red content-box; /* background color */
  border: 2px solid red; /* border */
  padding: 5px; /* space between border and background*/
  transform-origin: top;
}
button:before {
  left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  transform: skewX(var(--a));
  border-radius: var(--r) 0 0 var(--r);
}
button:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  transform: skewX(calc(-1*var(--a)));
  border-radius: 0 var(--r) var(--r) 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Play</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might rotate it around X:

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: .8em 3em 1em;
  color: #fff;
  perspective: 10em;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  background: #555;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  border-width: 2px 2px 3.5px;
  border-radius: .5em;
  box-shadow: 0 .5px 0 3.5px #555;
  padding: .3em .13em;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotateX(-40deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">PLAY</a>
```